# How to select a rows based on a Maximum value of a specific column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, max

I am trying to select a rows based on a Maximum value of a specific column value in SQL server 2008. I need to select the bookname and year based on the maximum edition.

Current table data:

```
    BookName    Year    Edition
Latest Science  2013    1
Latest Science  2014    2
Latest Science  2015    3
Easy Maths      2014    1
Easy Maths      2015    2
Magic vs Logic  2015    1
```

Output should be:

```
BookName    Year    Edition
Latest Science  2015    3
Easy Maths      2015    2
Magic vs Logics 2015    1
```

I tried but it result only one rows of entire table

```
SELECT     Book, year, edition
FROM         Book_info
where edition=(select max(edition) from book_info)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look up group by with having clauses.

Here is the entire script per your requirements which returns the results you're looking for.

```
USE [Test]

--table

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Book](

[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

[BookName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,

[Year] [int] NOT NULL,

[Edition] [int] NOT NULL

) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF

GO



USE [Test]

GO

--records

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Book]

([BookName]

,[Year]

,[Edition])

VALUES

('Last Science', 2013 ,1),

('Last Science', 2014 ,2),

('Last Science', 2015 ,3),

('Easy Maths', 2014 ,1),

('Easy Maths', 2015 ,2),

('Magic vs Logic', 2015 ,1)

GO

USE [Test]

GO

--query

SELECT

BookName,

MAX([Year]) AS Year,

MAX(Edition) AS Edition

FROM dbo.Book

GROUP BY

BookName

Order by MAX(Edition) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks @chdev77, group by is really helped me.

Comment: But I am facing one error, if I use the year its showing BookName. year is a invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Here I found the Answer for my question but  I want to know how to display the corresponding year,

    SELECT     BookName, MAX(Edition) AS Edition
                                FROM          Book_info AS Book_info_1
                                GROUP BY BookName order by Edition

Comment: Thanks @chdev77, Its works like a charm, I want one more that I don`t want to display the max of year but I need to show the corresponding year  of the maximum edition.

Comment: I would remove the max (year) and create an inner join to look up the year value.  Hopefully your book table has an id column.  I would create a new model honestly.  Remember if your queries are hard to write then your table structure may need to change. I would create a book table, book year table and a book edition table, with book.id being a foreign key to year and edition table.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
;WITH cte AS (
 SELECT *, 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BookName ORDER BY Edition DESC) AS rn
 FROM book_info
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE rn=1
```

Comment: Comma after `PARTITION BY` is not needed :)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot (obviously).   : )

Comment: I am little confused, could you please explain the code? Is the code start with semicolon?

Comment: @Tab Alleman, When I using your code sql  showing error, where to call the table name?  Kindly check and help.

Comment: oops, I left that out.  I have edited and corrected it.